# Flutter : Problems with textformfield

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a textformfield in my app which looks like below:

```
TextFormField(
           //maxLength: 02,
           textAlign: TextAlign.center,
           keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
           decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: textFieldInitVal.toString(),
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  ),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                   borderSide: BorderSide(
                     color: Colors.blue,
                     ),
                   ),
                ),
              //initialValue: textFieldInitVal.toString(),
              onChanged: (val) {
               if (int.parse(val) > 24) {
                  setState(() {
                    errorTxt = 'ERROR: Value cannot be more than 24 Hrs';
                  });
               } else {
                  setState(() {errorTxt = '';});
                  setState(() {value1 = int.parse(val).toDouble();});
                  //setState(() {value1 = double.parse(val);});
               }
             }
         ),
```

In the above snippet, both `textFieldInitVal` and `value1` are of type double.

I am facing two different problems:

1. Even if I use `textAlign: TextAlign.center`, I am unable to center the `labelText: textFieldInitVal.toString()`. The label goes and sticks to the left edge of the TextFormField. Adding some `padding` helps, but it also affects how the input text is placed, hence I am trying to avoid it.
2. In the `onChanged: (val) {` piece, when I do a `print(val)`, I notice that the TextFormField fails to take anything after decimal value and hence while converting to double from string for `val`, I am only getting whole numbers.

They look like very small issues, but am unable to figure a way out of this situation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even if I use textAlign: TextAlign.center, I am unable to center the labelText: textFieldInitVal.toString(). The label goes and sticks to the left edge of the TextFormField. Adding some padding helps, but it also affects how the input text is placed, hence I am trying to avoid it.

The property `textAlign` will align the text that you write inside the field in the middle of the field, but the label will stay at the left.

---

> In the onChanged: (val) { piece, when I do a print(val), I notice that the TextFormField fails to take anything after decimal value and hence while converting to double from string for val, I am only getting whole numbers.

Regarding this question, you need to use the `double` class instead of the `int` class to get the decimal when converting.

```
              onChanged: (val) {
               if (double.parse(val) > 24) {
                  setState(() {
                    errorTxt = 'ERROR: Value cannot be more than 24 Hrs';
                  });
               } else {
                 print(double.parse(val).toDouble());
                  setState(() {errorTxt = '';});
                  setState(() {value1 = int.parse(val).toDouble();});
               }
             }
```

Comment: I'll accept this one, since this is very close to how I solved the problem, but with a small caveat: